# By Default couchbaseCheckPoint type created for document in elasticsearch sync with couchbase

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I am new to elasticsearch and couchbase.I am using both in my project.My requirement is to sync couchbase bucket with elasticsearch indices by using couchbase XDCR.

In couchbase, Bucket name "Employee" and structure of one this document is

```
{
"empName":"Stev Jobs",
"dept":"IT",
"company":"xxxx",
"salary":"30000",
"country":"USA"
}
```

I created index in elasticsearch that is **employee** and also created cluster reference in couchbase with elasticsearch cluster.
After setting all this I started replication between **employee** bucket of couchbase and **employee** index of elasticsearch. It created indices in elasticsearch,but this index contains more than couchbase bucket documents.
My couchbase bucket employee has 182 records but in elasticsearch employee index showing docs 1025.
And In couchbase when sync it showing some error s.this error are like below

```
2015-05-22 09:07:44 [Vb Rep] Error replicating vbucket 98. Please see logs for details.
2015-05-22 09:07:44 [Vb Rep] Error replicating vbucket 697. Please see logs for details.
```

In elasticsearch my **employee** index docs  structure like

```
{

    "_index": "employee",
    "_type": "couchbaseCheckpoint",
    "_id": "vbucket921UUID",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "doc": {
            "uuid": "ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097"
        }
    }

}
```

And i write search query like,I run this query in http://127.0.0.1:9200/_plugin/head/

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/employee/_search/

    { 
      "query": {
             "match":{
                    "query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097",
                     "fields":["uuid"]
              }
        }
    }
```

It giving error

```
{

    "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[J2CjiG2vQqqrG2h5jlsudg][couchrecords][0]: SearchParseException[[couchrecords][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match":{"query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097","fields":["uuid"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[couchrecords] [match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]; }{[J2CjiG2vQqqrG2h5jlsudg][couchrecords][1]: SearchParseException[[couchrecords][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match":{"query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097","fields":["uuid"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[couchrecords] [match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]; }{[J2CjiG2vQqqrG2h5jlsudg][couchrecords][2]: SearchParseException[[couchrecords][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match":{"query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097","fields":["uuid"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[couchrecords] [match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]; }{[J2CjiG2vQqqrG2h5jlsudg][couchrecords][3]: SearchParseException[[couchrecords][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match":{"query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097","fields":["uuid"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[couchrecords] [match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]; }{[J2CjiG2vQqqrG2h5jlsudg][couchrecords][4]: SearchParseException[[couchrecords][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match":{"query":"ec88aeb16c00427698f079d8a3fa7097","fields":["uuid"]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[couchrecords] [match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?]; }]",
    "status": 400

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The couchbaseCheckpoint document is used by the plugin to save state for each vBucket, so that it can emulate the XDCR protocol correctly. That's why there are 1025 of them - 1024 vBuckets plus one global state doc.

The fact that you have 1025 docs in ElasticSearch means that you ONLY got the state docs and none of the actual docs got replicated. Did you set up mappings in ElasticSearch like it says in the installation guide? This looks like a problem with indexing, so the ElasticSearch log will actually have meaningful errors that will tell you why it can't index any of your documents. The Couchbase log only tells you that it couldn't replicate something

Comment: For this index i did mapping like { "mappings":{"couchbaseCheckpoint":{  "dynamic":"true","_source":{"includes":["doc.*"] },"dynamic_templates":[{
 "store_no_index":{"match":"*","mapping":{"store":"no","index":"no",    "include_in_all":false }}}]},"couchbaseDocument":{"_all":{"enabled":false  },"dynamic":"true","_source":{ "includes":["meta.*"]}," dynamic_templates":[{"all_strings_to_avoid_collisions":{     "match":"*" "mapping":{"store":"no","index":"not_analyzed", include_in_all":false,"type":"string",..how to solve this problem.Exactly where i gettingproblem with elasticsearch or couchbase

Comment: Take a look in the ES log to see what errors it prints when trying to index your documents.